# How do I change the background of my unity project in the code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game where the background switches to a different one. How would I change the background in code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you abandon the question?

Answer (score 0):

In the camera you can change the type of background with `clearFlags` property using `CameraClearFlags` enum you have options such as `Skybox` and `SolidColor` and you can change the color with `backgroundColor` property.

```cs
Camera.main.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.black;
```

To change the skybox you need to have a material with skybox shader and assign to the `RenderSettings` `skybox` property.

```cs
Camera.main.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Skybox;
RenderSettings.skybox = background; //background is a material with skybox shader
```

This works both in 2D and 3D projects.